# SELECT DISTINCT Returning duplicate values for DATE column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find the range of date values for a date datatype column in my one of my views.

I've searched many oracle forums looking for similar bug and no luck.

Columns for EPAServiceReport view:

```
EPASERVICEREPORT_KEY    NUMBER(10)
EQUIPMENT_KEY           NUMBER(10)
STARIDNO                VARCHAR2(60)
WORKORDERNUMBER         NVARCHAR2(50)
REPORT_ID               NVARCHAR2(50)
CREATEDDATE             DATE
```

SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT createddate 
FROM epaservicereport 
ORDER BY createddate
```

Results:

```
12-OCT-15
12-OCT-15
19-OCT-15
19-OCT-15
27-OCT-15
30-OCT-15
04-NOV-15
05-NOV-15
12-NOV-15
12-NOV-15
```

I expected to only see 1 row per value i.e. "distinct" but instead got every row from the view returned with many duplicate values.

Answer (score 7):

Your date column has time, too. So although it displays the same but actually it's different in time on a day.

You could use this to get distint date only:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(createddate)
FROM epaservicereport 
ORDER BY 1; --TRUNC(createddate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

**SQL Server:**

```
select distinct CONVERT(varchar(12),createddate,105)
FROM epaservicereport 
ORDER BY 1;
```

More on cast and convert here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

**Oracle:**

```
select distinct TO_CHAR(createddate,'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM epaservicereport 
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: The tag under the question says Oracle. Your suggestion will not work for Oracle.